# How to center image vertically in div

Tags: html, css, image, center, vertical-alignment

I have a div which has a height of 100vh so that it's always the height of the browser screen. Inside of this div I want to place an image and center it vertical to its parent.

The height is variable so I can't use fixed margins. My current Markup is as follows:

**HTML**

```
   <div class="textportfolio">

      <h1>This is a title</h1>

      <p class="textbio-small">
      The Roosevelt dime is the current ten-cent piece of the United States.
      </p>

      <img class="portfolio-slides-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/iheO43X.png">

   </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.textportfolio {
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    margin: 5%;
    background: #e9cca3;
    height: 100vh;
}

img.portfolio-slides-img {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    }
```

Does anybody know how to center the image vertically according to the browser height?

Here is the code snippet

```css
.textportfolio {
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    margin: 5%;
    background: #e9cca3;
    height: 100vh
}

img.portfolio-slides-img {
    margin-top: 15%;
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="textportfolio">
  <h1>This is a title</h1>
  
  <p class="textbio-small">
  The Roosevelt dime is the current ten-cent piece of the United States.
  </p>
  
  <img class="portfolio-slides-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/iheO43X.png">
  
  </div>
```

Comment: did you try position: absolute attibute?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are after. Is the image supposed to be centered and the text sit **vertically above** of the centered image **or** are you trying to center the whole text/image combo?

Comment: Only the image should be vertically centered inside of the (orange) div.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to vertically align an image inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use this css snippet:

```
.selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Applied to your sample: https://jsfiddle.net/nhdh8ycr/4/

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to set `position: relative;` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Centering things in CSS has been a long debated topic where people weigh all the factors and argue what the least convoluted way is.

Then in 2014, something called Flexbox came out and basically obsoleted all that.

When a container has `display: flex`, there's properties to align its children. And you can anchor it in the middle on either/both axis.

```
<div id="container">
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/i9xpVnQ.jpg" />
</div>
```

```
html, body {
  height: 100%; /* required to make body occupy the full viewport by default */
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* horizontal */
  justify-content: center; /* vertical */
}

img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5goboeey/1/

It's so ubiquitously convenient I think it continues to fly under the radar because people assume it can't be so straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this stackoverflow question could help you 
[jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div)

code is
**HTML**

```
<div class=frame>
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=3 />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.frame {
height: 25px;      /* equals max image height */
line-height: 25px;
width: 160px;
border: 1px solid red;

text-align: center; margin: 1em 0;
}
img {
background: #3A6F9A;
vertical-align: middle;
max-height: 25px;
max-width: 160px;
}
```

Comment: This works because the div where the image is placed ha a fixed height of 25px. But I have a variable height (browser window). So not a solution for my problem.

Comment: you can use it in % percentage .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.textportfolio {
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
  margin: 5%;
  background: #e9cca3;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

img.portfolio-slides-img {
  max-width: 40%;
  max-height: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 35%
}
```

```html
<div class="textportfolio">
  <h1>This is a title</h1>

  <p class="textbio-small">
    The Roosevelt dime is the current ten-cent piece of the United States.
  </p>

  <img class="portfolio-slides-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/iheO43X.png">

</div>
```